# Before zeroth law of thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

In my textbook and other places on internet, it is stated that [zeroth law of thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroth_law_of_thermodynamics) is called so because it was formulated long after the other three laws were already in practice. Also, according to my understanding of the zeroth law, it establishes temperature as a state function.

But well, I think that there are many concepts based on the other three laws where we use that temperature is a state function. For eg., we say that change in internal energy of an ideal gas is dependent only on temperature, but well if temperature is not a state function then $U$ can also not be stated as a state function.

So how did scientists work out all these things before they established the zeroth law? Or is it that it was actually accepted that temperature is a state function but they just took it for granted until someone pointed it out? Also, if we have a law for temperature, why leave pressure and volume out? I mean why don't we get a law for establishing them as a state function as well?

Comment: First they developed a general understanding of much that relates to temperature; then they decided to formulate a statement as brief as possible that would capture or imply large parts of what had been discovered.

Comment: So you are saying that temperature was already established as a state function, just that the scientists did not feel the need to set it out as a law. But then why create the zeroth law at all? Why did they all of a sudden feel the need to formalise the concepts that they had been using just fine for all those years? Also, why just temperature? What about other state functions like pressure or volume?

Comment: Actually, the zeroth law is not about the temperature as a function of state. It is about the meaning of temperature as an indicator of thermal equilibrium. It is similar to the concept of heat: one thing is to define it and another thing is to say something about being or not a function of state.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by 'indicator of thermal equilibrium'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zeroth law of thermodynamics has a strange status among the fundamental laws of this subject. Its statement is so simple that there are not many variations of its formulation. It can be seen as postulating the existence of a scalar quantity (the temperature) that uniquely characterizes the mutual thermal equilibrium of different systems. There has been some proposal to consider it as a consequence of the first and second law in the past. Even recently, it has been argued that thermodynamics and the concept of temperature could be developed without the zeroth law [(Kammerlander, P., & Renner, R. (2018)).](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.09726)

However, there is something in the zeroth law that goes beyond the definition of temperature. Some decades ago, Redlich ( Journal of Chemical Education, 47(11), 740 (1970)) observed that if we found a case where three systems having the same temperature are not in mutual thermal equilibrium, we would not discard the concept of temperature. Still, we would look for unknown interactions that have not been screened to leave only a thermal contact. In this respect, the zeroth principle still plays a role as a guideline about how we perform experiments.

Comment: First of all i have just started with thermodynamics course in my high school so i don't know much about statistical mechanics approach you and @MahdiKoorepaz were talking about . So, what i got is that the existence of the zeroth law is a rather controversial topic, with the controversies arising because of the different models proposed for understanding the basic laws of thermodynamics. In all these different models, we are reaching the definition of temperature but because of the different founding axioms for these models, in some we need the zeroth law in some we don't.

Comment: @AseemMittal, weel, my answer was not specifically adapted to the high school level. However, you can ignore all references to Statistical Mechanics, and your summary is pretty fair. The only thing that I would add, to help you to put in the right perspective the information you got is that there is nothing special with the zeroth law of Thermodynamics. Physics is not math, and the principles of thermodynamics are not axioms of mathematical theories. They have to summarize the results of many experiments and ( establish a link between concepts and experiments. (continue)

Comment: As a result of such status, discussion on the principles is an on-going activity. Recent advances in nanotechnologies have motivated new scrutiny on all the principles of thermodynamics to understand how to adapt them to atomic-scale experiments. And a similar status is shared also by the principles of mechanics. The way we formulate today Newton's laws is quite different from the original formulation. That's Physics!

Comment: Thank you and I think I get what you are trying to say. Physics and its principles are concepts to explain what we are observing around us and should be treated as such. There is nothing set in stone and as long as we get new observations that are contradictory to our previously set laws, we have to adjust the laws to accomodate the new observations. Just like how we had to change our perception of light and adjust the laws governing its behaviour after the young's double slit experiment.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fundamental difference between temperature we knew before statistical mechanics and after Boltzmann. Before Boltzmann, temperature was a **relative** measure for the warmness of matters.

But Boltzmann (1875) defined entropy as $S(E)=k_B \ln W(E)$ and as its consequence $\frac{1}{T}=\frac{\partial S(E)}{\partial E}$ where $T$ here, is an **absolute** value. It is amazingly explained in [Schwabl G, Statistical Mechanics, section 2.4.1 (Definition of Temperature)](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783540323433?gclid=CjwKCAiAsaOBBhA4EiwAo0_AnHeh4MQYBx4W3ZhWeFuzigUPWp637ilqxdbavqMxbCEghAOOmFbu5xoCSucQAvD_BwE).

Of course at some limit these two values converge, but generaly one should have in mind the difference and yet, it took some years for scientists to build a bridge between these concepts.

Lastly, the state functions of a systems depends on which ensemble approach we take in statistical mechanics and sure, volume and pressure can also be state functions ([List of state funcions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_function#List_of_state_functions)).

Comment: The thermodynamic definition of temperature ($\frac{1}{T}=\frac{\partial S(E)}{\partial E}$ ) appeared much before Boltzmann and Statistical Mechanics. That definition **is not** a consequence of the statistical mechanics definition of entropy.

Comment: Could you please provide a reference? And what $\partial S$ refers before Boltzmann?

Comment: Every good thermodynamics textbook should explain how from the analysis of Carnot cycles one can arrive at the introduction of a function of state called entropy. The introduction (and naming) of entropy (in 1865) was due to Rudolf Clausius on the basis of purely thermodynamic arguments.

Comment: Of course, but in the Carnot cycle, the temperature is again a relative measure ($T_h$ or $T_c$) you cannot define temperature as an absolute value. Mathematically, it is an integration factor to compensate $Q$ inexact partial differentiation.
Instead, expanding $k_b \ln W(E)$ when $W(E)=W_{sys}(E_s)W_{bath}(E-E_s)$ for $E_s<<E$ and bath is huge, we assume that the coefficient of the first term in the expansion is constant and equal to temperature.

Comment: Once you have the integrating factor you have the entropy within an arbitrary constant which is fixed by the third law. It is a key point the possibility of showing that thermodynamic entropy coincides with the perfect gas temperature. The route you are mentioning about the expansion of  $\log W(E)$ does not remove the problem. How do you know that $k_B \log W(E,V,N)$ coincides with Clausius' definition of entropy?

Comment: There is no Clausius' entropy without temperature. Clausius theory defines the entropy, assuming $T$ is already defined. Although $dS_{rev} = dQ/T$ is mathematically similar to $1/T = dS/dE$, it is fundamentally different. But you can start from scratch with Boltzmann's approach and define $T$.

Comment: Thermodynamics stands even without statistical mechanics. Within the Causius approach, you start with an empirical temperature to end up with the possibility of substituting it with the definition in terms of entropy, showing at the end the self-consistency of the entire procedure. If you do not like the original Clausius approach, you can follow Caratheodory's approach.

Comment: It is not a matter of taste. It is a matter of precision. Energy can be defined in classical mechanics, but in quantum mechanics, we have a more precise approach, so we get ZPE, likewise the time in classical mechanics and relativity, etc. Statistical mechanics makes the relation between empirical laws of thermodynamics and underlying classical mechanics more clear, so we find more precise definitions in statistical mechanics. Thermodynamics is an asymptotic case of statistical mechanics. Of course, I do not hate Clausius :)